# SQL Server Backup through C#. File not found, could not load Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser what?!

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a backup. I dont understand what the error I'm getting points to. Which is not found?!

**this is the error message:** http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/1772/sql1.jpg

**my code:**

```
    public void BackupDatabase(String destinationPath)
    {
        try
        {
            //MY SERVER
            String userName = "NNIT-Admin";
            String password = "password";
            String serverName = @"RITZEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS";

            ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
            Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

            Backup BackupMgr = new Backup();
            BackupMgr.Devices.AddDevice(destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
            BackupMgr.Database = @"RITZEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS\Databases\D:\MY_THESIS\WORKING FILES\NNIT-RMS.MDF";
            BackupMgr.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            BackupMgr.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    private void BackUp_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String destinationPath = @"D:\";

        BackupDatabase(destinationPath);

    }
```

Comment: Is your database really called `[RITZEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS\Databases\D:\MY_THESIS\WORKING FILES\NNIT-RMS.MDF]`, or is that the file on disk? The documentation says it's the database name, not path. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.database.aspx

Comment: Yes that is really the name that appeared when I attached the .mdf file in sql server

Comment: Also, shouldn't `destinationPath` be `D:\MyBackup.bak` rather than `D:\`?

Comment: @todda.speot.is Thank you for pointing that out! I forgot to include the variable for the filename when I changed my code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a quick Google search](http://bit.ly/AaoonN) you need to install the 64-bit SMO components:

> I found as solution here:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=D09C1D60-A13C-4479-9B91-9E8B9D835CDC&displaylang=en
>
> Download and install
>
> X64 Package (SQLServer2005_XMO_x64.msi) - 14675 KB
>
> This installs the 64 bit smo objects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the mock. -_-" I also needed to enable the permission for my login.

Comment: @user1141604 No problemo. I hope you've bookmarked Google for future reference.